# SQLAlchemy different tables for relationship?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have the following tables/relationships defined:

```
class Post(Base):
   __table_name__ = "post"
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   text = Column(String(100))

class Comment(Base):
    __table_name__ = "comment"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    post_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("post.id"), nullable=False)
    text = Column(String(100))
```

Now, I want to have notifications of events, like "You were tagged in a comment" or "you were tagged in a post". Is there some way to have a foreign key relationship in SQLAlchemy that can point to either a comment or a post (or several other tables in reality)? Something like:

```
class Notification(Base):
    __table_name__ = "notification"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    target = relationship(??either post or comment??)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id")
    created_date = Column(Datetime, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

I suppose you could just put foreign keys to all the different types and make all but one null, but that seems ugly. I'd also rather not have multiple tables for each type of notification; as in `comment_notification` and `post_notification`. Any ideas?

Comment: Inheritance with `__polimorphic_identity__` stuff (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html), where you create base model, and use it as a base class for Post and Comment, and put reference to base model in Notification. But it will be 3 tables instead of 2 (base class will be table too). And you'll probably have hellish schema migration.

Comment: Yeah I've been looking into polymorphic stuff, can't quite figure out how to use it in this case though.

Comment: For examples of how this can be done look at [Generic Associations](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/examples.html#module-examples.generic_associations) examples of official documentation. Also you might find [Generic Relationships](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/generic_relationship.html) of `SQLAlchemy-Utils` library useful.